# VueJS: Date.now is less than is including todays date

Tags: vue.js

I am comparing 2 dates for a filtered search. I would like the object to go into the filtered results if the date is after today. I want any objects with today's date not to be included.

This is my code and it is moving any objects dated today into the filtered list.  'E' looks like this: "E": "4 June 2021", What am I doing wrong?

```js
    resultfilteredResults() {
          const filteredResults = this.results.filter((result) => {
            return Date.now() < new Date(E);
          });
          return filteredResults;
        },
```

Comment: Elaborate it more. what's the format of **results**? and from where **E** is coming from

Comment: in filter **result** should be used in return condition. that's why put the format of results here

Comment: This is the format for 'E': 4 June 2021. It is pulled in using AXIOS.

Comment: `this.results.filter((result) =>` i think what you are missing to use `result` in the below return condition. I mean on which basis you are filtering the data from `results`? Do something with `result` in the return statement or before to filter something

Comment: And if `E` is your `result.someAttribute` then there is mismatch in comparison..

`typeof` of  `Date.now()` is number and `typeof` of `new Date(E)` is object

Comment: Ah! I see. That makes sense. Thank you. What would be the best way to compare them? Im pretty new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `filter` callback doesn't seem to be comparing any objects of `this.results[]`. Make sure to return a value based on iterator item's data (i.e., `result` in this case):

```js
this.results.filter((result) => return /* something based on `result` */)
```

Assuming `this.results[]` array elements contained a `date` string property (e.g., `"2021-12-25"`), the `filter` callback should convert that property into a `Date` object with `new Date(result.date)`, then compare it to `new Date()`, which is the `Date` object for today:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    resultfilteredResults() {
      const today = new Date()
      return this.results.filter((result) => new Date(result.date) > today)
    }
  }
}
```